# MDX - Filter from unrelated measure group

Tags: ssas, mdx

So is it possible to filter by one measure group and take the distinct members/people from that measure group and use it as a filter from another query from a different measure group.

Equivalent sql query

```
SELECT 
    sum(spend)
FROM
    (SELECT distinct person_id FROM enrollment_fact WHERE program = 'blah') AS a
    JOIN
    (SELECT person_id, sum(spend) AS spend FROM sales_fact GROUP BY person_id) AS b 
    ON a.person_id = b.person_id
```

Assume I have two different measure groups in SSAS, one for spend and one from enrollment that are unrelated except for time and person_id

Also assume there are two many programs (thousands) to create columns/attributes for each person for each program to act as a member filter.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the same as:

```
SELECT sum(spend) AS spend 
FROM   sales_fact 
WHERE  person_id IN 
(
  SELECT person_id 
  FROM   enrollment_fact 
  WHERE  program = 'blah'
  GROUP  BY person_id
)
```

If both these measure groups are in the same cube and the person_id dimension is shared then it looks possible in `mdx`.

The sub-query could be done with the `NonEmpty` function:

```
NONEMPTY( 
  [person].[person_id].[person_id].MEMBERS
, (  
     [program].[program].[blah]
   , [measures].[someEnrollmentMeaure]
  )
)
```

So adding this to an `mdx` WHERE clause will slice the cube by these person_ids:

```
SELECT
   [measures].[someEnrollmentMeaure] ON 0   
FROM [youCube]
WHERE
  NONEMPTY( 
      [person].[person_id].[person_id].MEMBERS
     ,(  
        [program].[program].[blah]
       ,[measures].[someEnrollmentMeaure]
      )
    );
```

Comment: Thank you!  I feel like I tried almost every other variation, but gave the correct answer.

Comment: @KevinGrossman no worries Kevin - glad it helped (I upped your question)